# updating nx to 9.2.4 fails: incompatible prettier

Tags: nrwl-nx

```
Package "@nrwl/workspace" has an incompatible peer dependency to "prettier" (requires "^1.19.1", would install "2.0.4")
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
```

How to fix this?

`npm run update --force` does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can run **ng** update instead:

```
ng update @nrwl/workspace --force
```